# Untraceable word in a combination of LP fragments

Tags: vocabulary, greek, sappho

LP 68(b) and 69 [have been combined](https://www.academia.edu/8829793/Due_sequenze_saffiche_in_P.Oxy._1787_Esili_e_i_tre_carmi_dellultima_colonna_ms._in_SemRom_10_2007_) into a single text by the impression that they were «ex eadem parte papyri» and by the one letter split between the two. The resulting text, found in 6.A.iv [here](https://michelegorini.blogspot.com/2019/05/the-rest-of-sappho.html), has been supplemented to contain the word (ἐ)θύραμεν (prodelided), supposedly meaning «ci dilettammo» (we delighted). I have not been able to find the base word for this verb form. θυράω, θυρῶ, θυρέω, θυράιω don't exist according to Perseus, and θυράζω means "thrust out of doors", not at all similar to "delighted". So what verb is this?

**More translations**

[Gennaro Tedeschi's anthology](https://arts.units.it/retrieve/handle/11368/2846729/50615/Saffo%202015%20EUT.pdf), translating the fragment, gives "scherzavamo", "we joked". [Ferrari's *Una Mitra per Cleis*](https://www.academia.edu/7893820/Sapphos_Gift._The_Poet_and_Her_Community_bozze_Ann_Arbor_2010), in English translation, has "we took pleasure", which is probably the translated version of "ci dilettammo".